# Add more strings in an object with PHP

Tags: php, json

How can I add more strings to this object with PHP?
I have managed to generate strings, but I cannot add more strings to an object, nor remove the last comma.

Like this:

Before,

```
{
    "themes":[
    {
        "name": "Amelia",
        "description": "Sweet and cheery.",
        "thumbnail": "http://bootswatch.com/amelia/thumbnail.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

After,

```
{
    "themes":[
            {
        "name": "juan",
        "description": "esto es un ejemplo.",
        "thumbnail": "http://example.com"
        },
                {
        "name": "juan2",
        "description": "esto es un ejemplo2.",
        "thumbnail": "http://example2.com"
        },
    ]
}
```

**Update code:**

```
    // $_POST = Request::post
    if (Request::post('theme_title')) $theme_title = Request::post('theme_title'); else $theme_title = '';
    if (Request::post('theme_img')) $theme_img  = Request::post('theme_img'); else $theme_img = '';
    if (Request::post('theme_desc')) $theme_desc = Request::post('theme_desc'); else $theme_desc = '';

    $jsonfile = 'events.json';

    $data->themes[] = (object)array(
        "name"        => $theme_title,
        "description" => $theme_img,
        "thumbnail"   => $theme_desc

    );

    $json = str_replace('\/','/',json_encode( $data ));

    // $_POST = Request::post
    if (Request::post('Themes_add')){

          // file_put_contents
         File::setContent( $jsonfile, $json,$create_file = true, $append = true, );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"juan2", that's funny.  Something like this:

```
$obj->themes[] = (object)array(
    "name"        => "juan2",
    "description" => "esto es un ejemplo2.",
    "thumbnail"   => "http://example2.com"
);
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, but this only generated not add.

Comment: You are doing something else wrong then.  Here, `$obj` is your top-level object.  As long as that is correct, this *will* add the new entry to the object's `themes` array.

Comment: Also, make sure to up-vote answers that you feel were helpful if you'd like people to continue to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine this is just a dictionary object so you can do:

```
obj["key1"] = [];
obj["key2"] = [];

{
    "themes":[
            {
        "name": "juan",
        "description": "esto es un ejemplo.",
        "thumbnail": "http://example.com"
        },
                {
        "name": "juan2",
        "description": "esto es un ejemplo2.",
        "thumbnail": "http://example2.com"
        },
    ],
    "key1":[],
    "key2":[]
}
```

Or to add another object stored in $person to the themes key you can:

```
obj["themes"][] = $person;
```

Comment: Huh? Either you don't understand the question, or I don't. :)

Comment: It is possible I don't understand the question.  I thought he wanted to add another key to some dictionary object.  but looking at the example, I think you are right he wants to add to the themes list.